# css opacity background Not affect image

Tags: css, image, opacity

I want the White background of each post to have a little opacity effect, so I did:

```
.post{
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.75;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 0px; 
    }
```

Now the images in each post get the opacity effect too, which I dont want,  how can I solve this problem ??

the site:  http://crystalise.tw/xi/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`opacity` applies to the background and the content.
You can use `background` `rgba` to define a semi-transparent background.

```
.post{
   background: #FFF; /* Solid white for old browsers */
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75); /* 0.75 opacity background white for modern browsers */
   border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using RGBA colors, these are give in the same format as an RGB with an alpha (or transparency value).

In your example, the a 75% white would become `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)`

You should change your code to:

```
.post{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 0px; 
}
```

You can use an online converter to change HEX (#FFFFF) RGB (255,255,255) and HTML (white) colors, many of these exist online.